# How to store JSON object into PostgreSQL using JSONB data type inside table and PostgreSQL JDBC driver

Tags: json, postgresql, jdbc, kotlin, micronaut

I want to save following json object into PostgreSQL db table **as jsonb**

```
{
  "fname":"john",
  "lname:"doe",
}
```

I am currenlty using PGObject to create object and set type to jsonb and pass value as json string

Looking for a better approach with micronaut-data and micronaut
**Is there any native data type supported in micronaut-data to convert the Java object to JSON and store in db?**
How to save the data using postgres jdbc driver

**typecasting in query using :jsonb is already tried with raw jdbc if it works with micronaut-data / predator how to do it?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can use PGObject and Jackson Object mapper to save the json in Postgres

```
val person=PGobject()
person.type="jsonb"
person.value=ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString("{"fname":"john","lname":"doe"}")
```

now person object can be passed to JDBC driver for storing data as jsonb