# Updating JSON col in java throws type exception

Tags: java, json, postgresql, eclipselink

I'm trying to update a Json column and completely replace the json. The record is inserted using the PBObject method. But I keep getting the error below.

```
22-Dec-2020 09:03:15.087 WARNING [http-nio-9095-exec-1] util.server.exception.GenericEclipselinkExceptionHandler.handleException 
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "json_col" is of type json but expression is of type character varying
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
Position: 44
Error Code: 0
Call: UPDATE my_table SET JSON_COL = ? WHERE (ID = ?)
bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: UpdateObjectQuery(service.JsonRecord@7e67b84d)
```

The update looks like:

```
    PGobject pGobject = new PGobject();
    pGobject.setType("json");
    pGobject.setValue(record.getJsonDoc());

    doInsideTransaction(
             -> {
                Query query = em.createNativeQuery(
                        "update table set json_col=? where id=?"
                );
                query.setParameter(1, pGobject);
                query.setParameter(2, record.getId());
                query.executeUpdate();
            }
    );
```

Which calls

```
    public void doInsideTransaction(UnaryAction<EntityManager> action) {
        EntityManager em = entityManagerProvider.get();
        runTx(em, () -> action.run(em));
    }

    public void runTx(EntityManager em, Action action) {
        EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
        try {
            transaction.begin();
            action.run();
            transaction.commit();
        }
        catch (Exception error) {
            if (transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

I've also tried casting the json string using to_json and ::json, but that also returns the same error.

Java 8, Postgres 12.5. Postgres driver 9.4. EclipseLink 2.6.0

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57271199/how-to-store-json-object-into-postgresql-using-jsonb-data-type-inside-table-and

Comment: Nope. I've tried setting jsonb in the PGobject. Using native queries. Same exception. I'm wondering if this is a problem with the driver and postgres version, because the native query version works on Postgres 10.

Comment: JPA doesn't know anything about a PGobject or how to handle it - it isnt part of JPA or even JDBC. Try just passing your JSON string instead.